# Ignore data written to serial port until read using pyserial

Tags: pyserial

I have the same problem as shown in this post, but the solution posed did not quite work, though helped.

[Reading a Serial Port - Ignore portion of data written to serial port for certain time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19874623/reading-a-serial-port-ignore-portion-of-data-written-to-serial-port-for-certai)

However, I think that Farmer Joe had the same problem with the solution - the data was sometimes cut in half, for example:

```
b'2.36\r\n'
b'2.36\r\n'
b'2.36\r\n'
b'\n'
b'\r\n'
b'36\r\n'
b'2.36\r\n'
b'2.36\r\n'
```

but the final solution was never posted!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a simple that involves closing and opening the port when required, rather than flushing the com port of buffered data when it needs to be read - this work when reading intermittently.

```
serial.open()

while (serial.inWaiting()==0): #wait until there is data
    pass

valueRead = serial.readline()
serial.close()
```

The second solution was to throw the first value away. I found this method work well when reading at a required frequency. For example, when data is sent to the com port at 1000Hz, and the port is read with a frequency of 0.1Hz, 100 samples are read over a period of 1s.

```
serial.flushInput()
serial.readline() #do not save this value - throw away

while (serial.inWaiting()==0): #wait until there is data
    pass

valueRead = serial.readline() #keep this value
```